# Installing error when trying to npm install

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js, and I've been trying to npm install some modules - namely, cheerio, express and request. But I keep getting this:

```
npm WARN package.json node-web-scrape@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json node-web-scrape@0.0.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json node-web-scrape@0.0.1 No license field.
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-16500-38020820\registry.npmjs.org\jsdom\-\jsdom-7.2.2.tgz.1538180439' -> 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-16500-38020820\registry.npmjs.org\jsdom\-\jsdom-7.2.2.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cheerio"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
```

But the folder node_modules still appears in my directory. So OK, I try stuff on it. My main.js file has the following:

```
var request = require('request');

console.log("Hello, World!")
```

That's all it's got. Immediately, it breaks:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Crawler>node main
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Crawler\node_modules\request\node_modules\bl\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_duplex.js:21:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `npm` version 2.15.8, windows has a limit of folder depth. Update your `npm` to `npm@3`.

```
npm install -g npm@3 

npm cache clear
```

Then, delete your `node_modules/` before installing the npm modules(`cheerio`, `express`, `request`)

Source: BountySource